# runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit

Tags: go, cron

I have booking SAAS system in which I have thousands of merchants which run their business over this platform.

To complete their bookings on daily basis I have a cron which runs every 5 mins. In this cron, I have a scheduler api which is called inside main go routine but completed independently using another go routine along with execute command. I suddenly started getting this error on my cron system.

```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
```

Here is my code structure:

```
package cron

import (
    "gopkg.in/robfig/cron.v3"
)
func RunCron() {
    c := cron.New()
    c.AddFunc("@every 0h5m0s", SendBookingMail)
    c.Start()
}
func SendBookingMail() {
    // this function get all merchants & issue curl command for api url for each merchant. and then the below function is executed. 
}

func sendMailCron() {
    completeBkMailData := struct {
        Booking         models.Booking    `json:"booking"`
        TestCustomerIds []int             `json:"test_customer_ids"`
        SmsPermission   bool              `json:"sms_permission"`
        SmsKeys         map[string]string `json:"sms_keys"`
    }{
        booking,
        testCids,
        smsPermission,
        smsKeys,
    }
    b, err := json.Marshal(completeBkMailData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    jsonString := string(b)
    command := "https://example.com/booking-mail"
    StartCurlCommand(command, "POST", jsonString)
}

func StartCurlCommand(url, reqType, jsonData string, headers ...string) error {
   var ip, userAgent, bearerToken string
   var cmd *exec.Cmd
   if len(headers) > 0 {
      ip = headers[0]
      userAgent = headers[1]
      bearerToken = headers[2]
   }
   if reqType == "POST" {
      cmd = exec.Command("curl", "-H", "Connection: close", "--no-keepalive", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-X", "POST", "-d", jsonData, url)
   } else {
      cmd = exec.Command("curl", "-H", "Connection: close", "--no-keepalive", url)
   }
   var out bytes.Buffer
   var stderr bytes.Buffer
   cmd.Stdout = &out
   cmd.Stderr = &stderr
   err := cmd.Start()
   if err == nil {
      go func(cmd *exec.Cmd) {
         _ = cmd.Wait()
      }(cmd)
   }
   return err
}
```

I have already searched for this and found that there can be some sort of recursion in the code. But I am not able to identify where it is. Please help what is wrong here ?

Comment: The panic should have printed a stack trace, but you have not included it in your post. The stack trace will normally very clearly show a runaway recursion, if that's the problem.

Comment: As a side note, why are you using curl? Go has a builtin http client, there's normally no reason to use curl. (Also, you're doing it incorrectly because you ignore the return value)

Comment: For all we know the infinite recursion might be in the code you omitted from `SendBookingMail`. It may also be caused by `models.Booking`, or any of its members, incorrectly implementing the `json.Marshaler` interface. Or it may be caused by `models.Booking`, or any of its members, holding a pointer to itself.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But the code was running successfully from last 4-5 months with no problem at all with this structure. So I am not able to understand what is the problem.

Comment: Include the full stack trace in the question.

Comment: @CAFxX thanks for your useful hint. There was recursion mentioned in the stack trace. I fixed that. Now the system is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

`goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit` means you have **infinite recursion** (or too deep recursion) in your program. Call stack is a limited resource, so recursion should be used sparingly.

Example:

```
package main

func test(x int) int {
    return x + test(x+1)
}

func main() {
    test(1)
}
```

Print a panic:

```
$ go run .
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
runtime: sp=0xc020160398 stack=[0xc020160000, 0xc040160000]
fatal error: stack overflow

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x474d4b, 0xe)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1116 +0x72
runtime.newstack()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/stack.go:1067 +0x78d
runtime.morestack()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:449 +0x8f

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.test(0xffffdf, 0x0)
        /home/test/gtest/test.go:3 +0x50 fp=0xc0201603a8 sp=0xc0201603a0 pc=0x45dcd0
main.test(0xffffde, 0x0)
        /home/test/gtest/test.go:4 +0x2f fp=0xc0201603c8 sp=0xc0201603a8 pc=0x45dcaf
main.test(0xffffdd, 0x0)
        /home/test/gtest/test.go:4 +0x2f fp=0xc0201603e8 sp=0xc0201603c8 pc=0x45dcaf
main.test(0xffffdc, 0x0)
        /home/test/gtest/test.go:4 +0x2f fp=0xc020160408 sp=0xc0201603e8 pc=0x45dcaf
main.test(0xffffdb, 0x0)
        /home/test/gtest/test.go:4 +0x2f fp=0xc020160428 sp=0xc020160408 pc=0x45dcaf
main.test(0xffffda, 0x0)
        /home/test/gtest/test.go:4 +0x2f fp=0xc020160448 sp=0xc020160428 pc=0x45dcaf
main.test(0xffffd9, 0x0)
        /home/test/gtest/test.go:4 +0x2f fp=0xc020160468 sp=0xc020160448 pc=0x45dcaf
main.test(0xffffd8, 0x0)
        /home/test/gtest/test.go:4 +0x2f fp=0xc020160488 sp=0xc020160468 pc=0x45dcaf
main.test(0xffffd7, 0x0)
        /home/test/gtest/test.go:4 +0x2f fp=0xc0201604a8 sp=0xc020160488 pc=0x45dcaf
. . .
```

From the goroutine trace we can see that the issue is in `test.go` at line `4`, which is the recursive call to line `3`. That should give us enough knowledge to fix our code.

Answer (score 0):

> . But I am not able to identify where it is.

That might be because [issue 7181](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7181) has yet to be released.

> Any way to vote on this? Our dev team just spent a day trying to guess which part of our code might have been in the stack because our entire codebase was elided from the trace.

[commit 3a81338](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/3a81338622eb5c8b94f11001855e2a68a9e36bed) was reverted, but using a patched Go with this commit, just for testing, would help: instead of printing massive stack traces during
endless recursion, which spams users and aren't useful, it now prints out
the top and bottom 50 frames.

That would go a long way to help identify the root cause for the recursion.

The [OP Amandeep Kaur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7533957/amandeep-kaur) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625277/runtime-goroutine-stack-exceeds-1000000000-byte-limit?noredirect=1#comment123068142_69625277):

> There was recursion mentioned in the stack trace.
> I fixed that. Now the system is working fine.